# Insert selected multiple records to a table from existing table with another value

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, bulkinsert

My first table is like this

Voter

```
userID  | lgDiv 
--------------------
   1     |   3
   2     |   4
   3     |   6
   4     |   3
   5     |   3
```

In my second table, both `userID` and `elecID` are primary keys

VoterElection

```
voterID | elecID | voterType| votingStatus
--------------
   1      |  1   | Normal  | Active
   2      |  1   | Normal  | Active
   3      |  3   | Normal  | Active
```

I want to insert some selected rows of Voter table to the `VoterElection` table with electionID, `voterType` and `votingStatus`. `electionID,` `voterType` and `votingStatus` are same values for all the selected items from the Votertable.

`userID` of Voter table will be voterID of VoterElection table.

Furthermore Assume that I select all users whose lgDiv is 3 like this

```
        SELECT userID FROM Voter WHERE lgDiv=3 ;
```

According to the data I have given here it will select 3 records.

I want to insert all three records I selected from Voter to VoterElection with elecID, voterType and votingStatus. For all the records elecID, voterType and voting status will be the same.

Assume that I select elecID =3 voterType='Normal' and votingStatus='Active' to all three records. 
After insert it should look like this.

VoterElection

```
voterID | elecID | voterType | votingStatus
--------------------------------------------
   1    |  1     | Normal    | Active
   4    |  1     | Normal    | Active
   5    |  1     | Normal    | Active
```

This is what I could grab by searching

```
INSERT INTO VoterElection (voterID)
   SELECT userID  
   FROM Voter 
   WHERE lgDiv = 3;
```

How can I include `elecId, voterType` and `votingStatus` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add the values in your SELECT INTO:

```
INSERT INTO VoterElection (voterID, elecID, voterType, votingStatus)
     SELECT userID, 1, 'Normal', 'Active' FROM Voter WHERE lgDiv=3;
```

You can change the values 1, 'Normal', 'Active' to whatever you want.